# Find all controls of an external form from its handle

Tags: delphi, winapi

I would like to be able to find all the components/controls of a form of an external application from its handle.

I am a total beginner with WinApi and I am totally lost.

I can get the text of the control of the form when I know its handle (for that I use [windose](http://www.greatis.com/delphicb/windowse/)), but sometimes, for example, buttons on this form have no handle of their own.

I think that if I could loop over everything I can find on a form, that is to say make a list of all its children, I could find the ones that interest me.

Is this possible? Can you give me some hints, links, code examples? Anything to learn and succeed from.

Comment: Look at the Win32 API `FindWindow/Ex()` and `EnumChildWindows()` functions. Note, however, that non-windowed controls are not going to show up in these functions. The only way to access those kind of controls externally is if their parent window exposes them to UIAutomation or Accessibility APIs.

Comment: OK, thanks. I found that the buttons are on the WPF window... so no handler but is it possible to trigger the "onclick" event since this procedure is implemented ?

Comment: Because if it is not the case I will stop looking and click them by simulating a mouse click with the x,y coordinates...

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) allows you to both discover UI elements, as well as interact with them. The standard WPF controls implement the required automation interfaces.

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect, I'll look for it here